# JFrame not drawing

Tags: java, swing, jframe, java-2d, paintcomponent

I'm making a pong game with a JFrame but it's not drawing.

```java
package src;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Pong_Game extends JFrame{
public void Init()
{
    setTitle("Pong");
    setSize(500, 500);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
}
}
```

My window is just blank, why? One thing which might be worth noting is that the paintComponent method seems like a lot of people spell it differently or use it differently so I think I did something wrong.

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete. Are you calling Init? Where is your `main` method? It helps if we can run something.

Comment: `JFrame` class hasn't `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method only `paintComponents(Graphics g)`

Comment: I called Init frame the main method.

Comment: Change `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` to `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` and recompile for more info.  It is generally best to do custom painting in a `JPanel` or `BufferedImage` than attempt custom painting in a top level container like frame.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry sir i checked it should be override. I posted wrong answer but i meant to say was you have to call base class function to paint jframe :)